# How do I efficiently iterate over each entry in a Java Map?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, iteration

If I have an object implementing the `Map` interface in Java and I wish to iterate over every pair contained within it,  what is the most efficient way of going through the map?

Will the ordering of elements depend on the specific map implementation that I have for the interface?

Comment: In Java 8 using Lambda Expression: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25616206/1503859

Comment: Java 8: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-java-map/32343110#32343110

Comment: The easiest way is:         `hashMap.map {Log.d(TAG, it.key, it.value)}`

Answer (score 5893, accepted):

```java
Map<String, String> map = ...
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```

On Java 10+:

```java
for (var entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: If you do that, then it won't work as Entry is a nested Class in Map.
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: you can write the import as "import java.util.Map.Entry;" and it will work.

Comment: @Pureferret The only reason you might want to use an iterator is if you need to call its `remove` method. If that is the case, [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1295383/829571) shows you how to do it. Otherwise, the enhanced loop as shown in the answer above is the way to go.

Comment: I believe the form Map.Entry is clearer than importing the inner class into the current namespace.

Comment: Note that you can use `map.values()` or `map.keySet()` if you want to loop through values or keys only.

Comment: The order in which register were inserted isn't respected when you loop them after

Comment: @JosiahYoder No need to import the inner class `Map.Entry` since `var` handling the reference for you.

Comment: This post is such a mess. People wrote an answer in 2008 and updated it 15 years later and it looks nothing like the original solution and the comments don't match

Answer (score 1597):

To summarize the other answers and combine them with what I know, I found 10 main ways to do this (see below). Also, I wrote some performance tests (see results below). For example, if we want to find the sum of all of the keys and values of a map, we can write:

1. Using **iterator** and **Map.Entry**

   ```
   long i = 0;
   Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
       Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> pair = it.next();
       i += pair.getKey() + pair.getValue();
   }
   ```
2. Using **foreach** and **Map.Entry**

   ```
   long i = 0;
   for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> pair : map.entrySet()) {
       i += pair.getKey() + pair.getValue();
   }
   ```
3. Using **forEach** from Java 8

   ```
   final long[] i = {0};
   map.forEach((k, v) -> i[0] += k + v);
   ```
4. Using **keySet** and **foreach**

   ```
   long i = 0;
   for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
       i += key + map.get(key);
   }
   ```
5. Using **keySet** and **iterator**

   ```
   long i = 0;
   Iterator<Integer> itr2 = map.keySet().iterator();
   while (itr2.hasNext()) {
       Integer key = itr2.next();
       i += key + map.get(key);
   }
   ```
6. Using **for** and **Map.Entry**

   ```
   long i = 0;
   for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> entries = map.entrySet().iterator(); entries.hasNext(); ) {
       Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = entries.next();
       i += entry.getKey() + entry.getValue();
   }
   ```
7. Using the Java 8 **Stream API**

   ```
   final long[] i = {0};
   map.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> i[0] += e.getKey() + e.getValue());
   ```
8. Using the Java 8 **Stream API parallel**

   ```
   final long[] i = {0};
   map.entrySet().stream().parallel().forEach(e -> i[0] += e.getKey() + e.getValue());
   ```
9. Using **IterableMap** of `Apache Collections`

   ```
   long i = 0;
   MapIterator<Integer, Integer> it = iterableMap.mapIterator();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
       i += it.next() + it.getValue();
   }
   ```
10. Using **MutableMap** of Eclipse (CS) collections

    ```
    final long[] i = {0};
    mutableMap.forEachKeyValue((key, value) -> {
        i[0] += key + value;
    });
    ```

**Perfomance tests** (mode = AverageTime, system = Windows 8.1 64-bit, Intel i7-4790 3.60 GHz, 16 GB)

1. For a small map (100 elements), score 0.308 is the best

   ```
   Benchmark                          Mode  Cnt  Score    Error  Units
   test3_UsingForEachAndJava8         avgt  10   0.308 ±  0.021  µs/op
   test10_UsingEclipseMap             avgt  10   0.309 ±  0.009  µs/op
   test1_UsingWhileAndMapEntry        avgt  10   0.380 ±  0.014  µs/op
   test6_UsingForAndIterator          avgt  10   0.387 ±  0.016  µs/op
   test2_UsingForEachAndMapEntry      avgt  10   0.391 ±  0.023  µs/op
   test7_UsingJava8StreamApi          avgt  10   0.510 ±  0.014  µs/op
   test9_UsingApacheIterableMap       avgt  10   0.524 ±  0.008  µs/op
   test4_UsingKeySetAndForEach        avgt  10   0.816 ±  0.026  µs/op
   test5_UsingKeySetAndIterator       avgt  10   0.863 ±  0.025  µs/op
   test8_UsingJava8StreamApiParallel  avgt  10   5.552 ±  0.185  µs/op
   ```
2. For a map with 10000 elements,  score 37.606 is the best

   ```
   Benchmark                           Mode   Cnt  Score      Error   Units
   test10_UsingEclipseMap              avgt   10    37.606 ±   0.790  µs/op
   test3_UsingForEachAndJava8          avgt   10    50.368 ±   0.887  µs/op
   test6_UsingForAndIterator           avgt   10    50.332 ±   0.507  µs/op
   test2_UsingForEachAndMapEntry       avgt   10    51.406 ±   1.032  µs/op
   test1_UsingWhileAndMapEntry         avgt   10    52.538 ±   2.431  µs/op
   test7_UsingJava8StreamApi           avgt   10    54.464 ±   0.712  µs/op
   test4_UsingKeySetAndForEach         avgt   10    79.016 ±  25.345  µs/op
   test5_UsingKeySetAndIterator        avgt   10    91.105 ±  10.220  µs/op
   test8_UsingJava8StreamApiParallel   avgt   10   112.511 ±   0.365  µs/op
   test9_UsingApacheIterableMap        avgt   10   125.714 ±   1.935  µs/op
   ```
3. For a map with 100000 elements,  score 1184.767 is the best

   ```
   Benchmark                          Mode   Cnt  Score        Error    Units
   test1_UsingWhileAndMapEntry        avgt   10   1184.767 ±   332.968  µs/op
   test10_UsingEclipseMap             avgt   10   1191.735 ±   304.273  µs/op
   test2_UsingForEachAndMapEntry      avgt   10   1205.815 ±   366.043  µs/op
   test6_UsingForAndIterator          avgt   10   1206.873 ±   367.272  µs/op
   test8_UsingJava8StreamApiParallel  avgt   10   1485.895 ±   233.143  µs/op
   test5_UsingKeySetAndIterator       avgt   10   1540.281 ±   357.497  µs/op
   test4_UsingKeySetAndForEach        avgt   10   1593.342 ±   294.417  µs/op
   test3_UsingForEachAndJava8         avgt   10   1666.296 ±   126.443  µs/op
   test7_UsingJava8StreamApi          avgt   10   1706.676 ±   436.867  µs/op
   test9_UsingApacheIterableMap       avgt   10   3289.866 ±  1445.564  µs/op
   ```

Graphs (performance tests depending on map size)

[image]

Table (perfomance tests depending on map size)

```
          100     600      1100     1600     2100
test10    0.333    1.631    2.752    5.937    8.024
test3     0.309    1.971    4.147    8.147   10.473
test6     0.372    2.190    4.470    8.322   10.531
test1     0.405    2.237    4.616    8.645   10.707
test2     0.376    2.267    4.809    8.403   10.910
test7     0.473    2.448    5.668    9.790   12.125
test9     0.565    2.830    5.952   13.220   16.965
test4     0.808    5.012    8.813   13.939   17.407
test5     0.810    5.104    8.533   14.064   17.422
test8     5.173   12.499   17.351   24.671   30.403
```

All tests are on [GitHub](https://github.com/Vedenin/useful-java-links/blob/master/helloworlds/5.0-other-examples/src/main/java/other_examples/IterateThroughHashMapTest.java).

Comment: @Viacheslav : very nice answer. Just wondering how Java8 apis are hindered, in your benchmark, by capturing lambdas... (e.g. `long sum = 0; map.forEach( /* accumulate in variable sum*/);` captures the `sum` long, which may be slower than say `stream.mapToInt(/*whatever*/).sum` for example. Of course you can not always avoid capturing state, but that may be a reasonnable addition to the bench.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov: look at the mindblowingly large error values. Consider that a test result of `x±e` implies that there were result within the interval from `x-e` to `x+e`, so the fastest result (`1184.767±332.968`) ranges from `852` to `1518`, whereas the second slowest (`1706.676±436.867`) runs between `1270` and `2144`, so the results still overlap significantly. Now look at the slowest result, `3289.866±1445.564`, which implies diverging between `1844` and `4735` and you *know* that these test results are meaningless.

Comment: What about comparing the 3 main implementations : HashMap, LinkedHashMap and TreeMap ?

Comment: #1 and #6 are exactly the same. Using `while` vs. a `for` loop is not a different technique for iterating. And I am surprised they have such variation between them in your tests—which suggests that the tests are not properly isolated from external factors unrelated to the things you intend to be testing.

Comment: `#8` is a terrible example, because of the `parallel` there's now a race condition when adding to `i`.

Comment: @GPI Two of the java8 apis are slower because they use Streams, which are inherently slower. They do all the work of a for-each loop—that's how they're implemented internally—but they also do some work setting up the stream. So they're never faster than a standard loop, unless you can correctly use parallel processing. Of course, we don't use them for speed but for readability and maintainability. (And we use object oriented languages instead of faster procedural ones because the developer time now costs more than the computer time. They optimize developer time instead of production time.)

Comment: @ErikE Performance testing in Java is very hard, because we have no control over garbage-collecting, and I think because at some point the compiled classes may get optimized. In my trials, I run my tests for thousands of iterations, I interleave the different test cases, and I repeat my tests multiple times in each run. The first few runs are always slower. And when I plot speeds over time, I see time intervals where all my cases ran more slowly, probably due to garbage collection. And all cases see a performance improvement after a certain point, probably due to byte code optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but if it is so hard to understand Java's performance characteristics, then how is it not a piece of junk? Seriously, a for loop and a while loop shouldn't perform so much differently.

Comment: @MiguelMunoz thanks. The idea was not to compare stream vs imperative, but capturing vs non capturing lambdas. just out of curiosity, btw, it's not that important to the question.

Answer (score 345):

In Java 8 you can do it clean and fast using the new lambdas features:

```
 Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put("SomeKey", "SomeValue");
 map.forEach( (k,v) -> [do something with key and value] );

 // such as
 map.forEach( (k,v) -> System.out.println("Key: " + k + ": Value: " + v));
```

The type of `k` and `v` will be inferred by the compiler and there is no need to use `Map.Entry` anymore.

Easy-peasy!

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with a map, you can also use stream API on the entries returned by `map.entrySet().stream()` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

Comment: This won't work if you want to reference non-final variables declared outside your lambda expression from within the forEach()...

Comment: @Chris Correct. It won't work if you try to use *effectively non-final* variables from outside the lambda.

Answer (score 266):

Yes, the order depends on the specific Map implementation.

[@ScArcher2 has the more elegant Java 1.5 syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map/46908#46908). In 1.4, I would do something like this:

```
Iterator entries = myMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (entries.hasNext()) {
  Entry thisEntry = (Entry) entries.next();
  Object key = thisEntry.getKey();
  Object value = thisEntry.getValue();
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Prefer for-loop than while..
for(Iterator entries = myMap.entrySet().iterator(); entries.hasNext(); ) {...}
With this syntax the 'entries' scope is reduced to the for loop only.

Comment: @jpredham You are right that using the `for` construct as `for (Entry e : myMap.entrySet)` will not allow you to modify the collection, but the example as @HanuAthena mentioned it should work, since it gives you the `Iterator` in scope.  (Unless I'm missing something...)

Comment: IntelliJ is giving me errors on `Entry thisEntry = (Entry) entries.next();`: doesn't recognize `Entry`. Is that pseudocode for something else?

Comment: @JohnK try importing `java.util.Map.Entry`.

Comment: This solution will not work if you have a integer key and String key.

Answer (score 151):

Typical code for iterating over a map is:

```
Map<String,Thing> map = ...;
for (Map.Entry<String,Thing> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Thing thing = entry.getValue();
    ...
}
```

`HashMap` is the canonical map implementation and doesn't make guarantees (or though it should not change the order if no mutating operations are performed on it). `SortedMap` will return entries based on the natural ordering of the keys, or a `Comparator`, if provided. `LinkedHashMap` will either return entries in insertion-order or access-order depending upon how it has been constructed. `EnumMap` returns entries in the natural order of keys.

**(Update: I think this is no longer true.**) Note, `IdentityHashMap` `entrySet` iterator currently has a peculiar implementation which returns the same `Map.Entry` instance for every item in the `entrySet`! However, every time a new iterator advances the `Map.Entry` is updated.

Comment: EnumMap also has this peculiar behaviour along with IdentityHashMap

Comment: "LinkedHashMap will either return entries in [...] access-order [...]" ... so you access the elements in the order you access them? Either tautological, or something interesting which could use a digression. ;-)

Comment: @jpaugh Only direct accesses to the `LinkedHashMap` count. Those through `iterator`, `spliterator`, `entrySet`, etc., do not modify the order.

Comment: 1. *though* → *if*? 2. The last paragraph might benefit from a brush-up.

Answer (score 133):

Example of using iterator and generics:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = myMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (entries.hasNext()) {
  Map.Entry<String, String> entry = entries.next();
  String key = entry.getKey();
  String value = entry.getValue();
  // ...
}
```

Comment: You should put `Iterator` in a for loop to limit its scope.

Comment: @SteveKuo What do you mean by "limit its scope" ?

Comment: @StudioWorks `for (Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> entries = myMap.entrySet().iterator(); entries.hasNext(); ) {
  Map.Entry<K, V> entry = entries.next(); }`. By using that construct we limit the scope of (visibility of the variable) `entries` to the for loop.

Answer (score 109):

This is a two part question:

*How to iterate over the entries of a Map* - @ScArcher2 has [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46908/1851302) that perfectly.

*What is the order of iteration* - if you are just using `Map`, then strictly speaking, there are **no ordering guarantees**.  So you shouldn't really rely on the ordering given by any implementation.  However, the [`SortedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) interface extends `Map` and provides exactly what you are looking for - implementations will aways give a consistent sort order.

**[`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) is another useful extension** - this is a `SortedMap` with additional methods for finding entries by their ordered position in the key set.  So potentially this can remove the need for iterating in the first place - you might be able to find the specific `entry` you are after using the `higherEntry`, `lowerEntry`, `ceilingEntry`, or `floorEntry` methods.  The `descendingMap` method even gives you an explicit method of **reversing the traversal order**.

Answer (score 64):

FYI, you can also use `map.keySet()` and `map.values()` if you're only interested in keys/values of the map and not the other.

Answer (score 64):

The correct way to do this is to use the accepted answer as it is the most efficient. I find the following code looks a bit cleaner.

```
for (String key: map.keySet()) {
   System.out.println(key + "/" + map.get(key));
}
```

Comment: This is not the best approach, it's much more efficient to use the entrySet().  Findbugs will flag this code (see http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#WMI_WRONG_MAP_ITERATOR)

Comment: @JeffOlson meh, not really. 
map lookup is O(1) so both loops behave the same way. admittedly, it will be slightly slower in a micro benchmark but i sometimes do this as well because i hate writing the type arguments over and over again. Also this will quite likely never be your performance bottleneck, so go for it if it makes the code more readable.

Comment: @kritzikratzi but with the entrySet() approach, you're doing one lookup for each element, whereas with the keySet()/get() approach, you're doing two lookups for each element.  So in theory (haven't tested it), it is O(1) vs. 2 * O(1).  Or twice as long.  Right?

Comment: more in detail: `O(1) = 2*O(1)` is pretty much the definition of the big O notation. you're right in that it runs a bit slower, but in terms of complexity they're the same.

Comment: Look up in map is O(1), really?))))) Where on Earth it is O(1)?))) HashMap: First - you must calculate hash, second - search in array by hash, third! - linear search through all elements wich has the same hashCode, this calls 'collision', don't you hear about it? =) And what can you say about: TreeMap, ConcurrentSkipListMap are they 'O(1)', too?

Comment: @kornero good point, treemap lookup is O(log n), i only had hashmaps in mind (which are ~ O(1), collisions or not)

Comment: @kritzikratzi collisions in hashmaps makes complexity ~ O(n), and there is "Denial of Service via Algorithmic Complexity Attacks" based on this, you can read more about it here: http://www.cs.rice.edu/~scrosby/hash/CrosbyWallach_UsenixSec2003/

Comment: by collision or not i meant it doesn't matter if you a few collisions, obviously it's a different story if you have only collisions. so you're being pretty petty, but yep, what you're saying is true.

Comment: @Jeff Olson: the comments that the “Big O” complexity doesn’t change, when there is only a constant factor, is correct. Still, to me it matters whether an operation takes one hour or two hours. More important, it must be emphasized that the factor is **not** `2`, as iterating over an `entrySet()` does not bear a lookup at all; it’s just a linear traversal of all entries. In contrast, iterating over the `keySet()` and performing a lookup per key bears *one* lookup per key, so we’re talking about zero lookups vs. *n* lookups here, *n* being the size of the `Map`. So the factor is way beyond `2`…

Comment: @kornero: it might be worth noting that you don’t need the keys to have the same hashcode to have a collision; there’s already a collision when `hashcode % capacity` is the same. Starting with Java 8, the complexity for items having the same `hashcode % capacity`, but different `hashcode` or are `Comparable` falls back to `O(log n)` and only keys having the same hash code and not being `Comparable` impose `O(n)` complexity. But the statement that the complexity of a lookup can be more than `O(1)` in practice still holds.

Answer (score 58):

With **Java 8**, you can iterate Map using forEach and lambda expression,

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println((k + ":" + v)));
```

Answer (score 44):

With [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections), you would use the `forEachKeyValue` method on the [`MapIterable`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/blob/master/eclipse-collections-api/src/main/java/org/eclipse/collections/api/map/MapIterable.java) interface, which is inherited by the `MutableMap` and `ImmutableMap` interfaces and their implementations.

```
MutableMap<Integer, String> map = 
    Maps.mutable.of(1, "One", 2, "Two", 3, "Three");

MutableBag<String> result = Bags.mutable.empty();
map.forEachKeyValue((key, value) -> result.add(key + value));

MutableBag<String> expected = Bags.mutable.of("1One", "2Two", "3Three");
Assertions.assertEquals(expected, result);
```

The reason using `forEachKeyValue` with Eclipse Collections (EC) `Map` implementations will be more efficient than using `entrySet` is because EC `Map` implementations do not store `Map.Entry` objects. Using `entrySet` with EC `Map` implementations results in `Map.Entry` objects being generated dynamically. The `forEachKeyValue` method is able to avoid creating the `Map.Entry` objects because it can navigate the internal structure of the `Map` implementations directly. This is a case where there is a benefit of using an internal iterator over an external iterator.

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 43):

### Java 8

We have got `forEach` method that accepts a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). We have also got [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) APIs. Consider a map:

```
Map<String,String> sample = new HashMap<>();
sample.put("A","Apple");
sample.put("B", "Ball");
```

**Iterate over keys:**

```
sample.keySet().forEach((k) -> System.out.println(k));
```

**Iterate over values:**

```
sample.values().forEach((v) -> System.out.println(v));
```

**Iterate over entries (Using forEach and Streams):**

```
sample.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k + ":" + v)); 
sample.entrySet().stream().forEach((entry) -> {
            Object currentKey = entry.getKey();
            Object currentValue = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println(currentKey + ":" + currentValue);
        });
```

The advantage with streams is they can be parallelized easily in case we want to. We simply need to use `parallelStream()` in place of `stream()` above.

**`forEachOrdered` vs `forEach` with streams ?**
The `forEach` does not follow encounter order (if defined) and is inherently non-deterministic in nature where as the `forEachOrdered` does. So `forEach` does not guarantee that the order would be kept. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797579/foreach-vs-foreachordered-in-java-8-stream) for more.

Answer (score 41):

In theory, the most efficient way will depend on which implementation of Map. The official way to do this is to call `map.entrySet()`, which returns a set of `Map.Entry`, each of which contains a key and a value (`entry.getKey()` and `entry.getValue()`).

In an idiosyncratic implementation, it might make some difference whether you use `map.keySet()`, `map.entrySet()` or something else. But I can't think of a reason why anyone would write it like that. Most likely it makes no difference to performance what you do.

And yes, the order will depend on the implementation - as well as (possibly) the order of insertion and other hard-to-control factors.

[edit] I wrote `valueSet()` originally but of course `entrySet()` is actually the answer.

Answer (score 39):

### **Lambda** Expression Java 8

In Java 1.8 (Java 8) this has become lot easier by using **forEach** method from Aggregate operations(**Stream operations**) that looks similar to iterators from **Iterable** Interface.

Just copy paste below statement to your code and rename the **HashMap** variable from **hm** to your HashMap variable to print out key-value pair.

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
/*
 *     Logic to put the Key,Value pair in your HashMap hm
 */

// Print the key value pair in one line.

hm.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("key: " + k + " value:" + v));

// Just copy and paste above line to your code.
```

Below is the sample code that I tried using **Lambda Expression**. This stuff is so cool. Must try.

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    Random rand = new Random(47);
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 5) {
        i++;
        int key = rand.nextInt(20);
        int value = rand.nextInt(50);
        System.out.println("Inserting key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
        Integer imap = hm.put(key, value);
        if( imap == null) {
            System.out.println("Inserted");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Replaced with " + imap);
        }               
    }

    hm.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("key: " + k + " value:" + v));
    
Output:

Inserting key: 18 Value: 5
Inserted
Inserting key: 13 Value: 11
Inserted
Inserting key: 1 Value: 29
Inserted
Inserting key: 8 Value: 0
Inserted
Inserting key: 2 Value: 7
Inserted
key: 1 value:29
key: 18 value:5
key: 2 value:7
key: 8 value:0
key: 13 value:11
```

Also one can use **Spliterator** for the same.

```
Spliterator sit = hm.entrySet().spliterator();
```

**UPDATE**

---

Including documentation links to Oracle Docs.
For more on **Lambda** go to this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and must read [Aggregate Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/) and for Spliterator go to this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html).

Answer (score 36):

**Java 8:**

You can use lambda expressions:

```
myMap.entrySet().stream().forEach((entry) -> {
    Object currentKey = entry.getKey();
    Object currentValue = entry.getValue();
});
```

For more information, follow [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: @injecteer: Seems the motive of lambda expressions

Comment: You don’t need a stream if you just want to iterate over a map. `myMap.forEach( (currentKey,currentValue) -> /* action */ );` is much more concise.

Answer (score 32):

In Map one can Iteration over `keys` and/or `values` and/or `both (e.g., entrySet)`  depends on one's interested in_ Like:

1. Iterate through the [`keys -> keySet()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) of the map:

   ```
   Map<String, Object> map = ...;

   for (String key : map.keySet()) {
       //your Business logic...
   }
   ```
2. Iterate through the [`values -> values()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29) of the map:

   ```
   for (Object value : map.values()) {
       //your Business logic...
   }
   ```
3. Iterate through the [`both -> entrySet()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) of the map:

   ```
   for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
       String key = entry.getKey();
       Object value = entry.getValue();
       //your Business logic...
   }
   ```

Moreover, there are 3 different ways to iterate through a HashMap. They are as below:

```
//1.
for (Map.Entry entry : hm.entrySet()) {
    System.out.print("key,val: ");
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "," + entry.getValue());
}

//2.
Iterator iter = hm.keySet().iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    Integer key = (Integer)iter.next();
    String val = (String)hm.get(key);
    System.out.println("key,val: " + key + "," + val);
}

//3.
Iterator it = hm.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
    Integer key = (Integer)entry.getKey();
    String val = (String)entry.getValue();
    System.out.println("key,val: " + key + "," + val);
}
```

Answer (score 30):

Try this with Java 1.4:

```
for ( Iterator entries = myMap.entrySet().iterator(); entries.hasNext();) {

  Entry entry = (Entry) entries.next();

  System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());

  //...
}
```

Answer (score 27):

The ordering will always depend on the specific map implementation.
Using Java 8 you can use either of these:

```
map.forEach((k,v) -> { System.out.println(k + ":" + v); });
```

Or:

```
map.entrySet().forEach((e) -> {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue());
        });
```

The result will be the same (same order). The entrySet backed by the map so you are getting the same order. The second one is handy as it allows you to use lambdas, e.g. if you want only to print only Integer objects that are greater than 5:

```
map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e-> e.getValue() > 5)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The code below shows iteration through LinkedHashMap and normal HashMap (example). You will see difference in the order:

```
public class HMIteration {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Object, Object> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<Object, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i=10; i>=0; i--) {
            linkedHashMap.put(i, i);
            hashMap.put(i, i);
        }

        System.out.println("LinkedHashMap (1): ");
        linkedHashMap.forEach((k,v) -> { System.out.print(k + " (#="+k.hashCode() + "):" + v + ", "); });

        System.out.println("\nLinkedHashMap (2): ");

        linkedHashMap.entrySet().forEach((e) -> {
            System.out.print(e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue() + ", ");
        });


        System.out.println("\n\nHashMap (1): ");
        hashMap.forEach((k,v) -> { System.out.print(k + " (#:"+k.hashCode() + "):" + v + ", "); });

        System.out.println("\nHashMap (2): ");

        hashMap.entrySet().forEach((e) -> {
            System.out.print(e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue() + ", ");
        });
    }
}
```

Output:

```
LinkedHashMap (1):
10 (#=10):10, 9 (#=9):9, 8 (#=8):8, 7 (#=7):7, 6 (#=6):6, 5 (#=5):5, 4 (#=4):4, 3 (#=3):3, 2 (#=2):2, 1 (#=1):1, 0 (#=0):0,
LinkedHashMap (2):
10 : 10, 9 : 9, 8 : 8, 7 : 7, 6 : 6, 5 : 5, 4 : 4, 3 : 3, 2 : 2, 1 : 1, 0 : 0,
HashMap (1):
0 (#:0):0, 1 (#:1):1, 2 (#:2):2, 3 (#:3):3, 4 (#:4):4, 5 (#:5):5, 6 (#:6):6, 7 (#:7):7, 8 (#:8):8, 9 (#:9):9, 10 (#:10):10,
HashMap (2):
0 : 0, 1 : 1, 2 : 2, 3 : 3, 4 : 4, 5 : 5, 6 : 6, 7 : 7, 8 : 8, 9 : 9, 10 : 10,
```

Answer (score 25):

Most compact with Java 8:

```
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 25):

These are all the possible ways of iterating HashMap.

```
HashMap<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    map.put(1, "David"); // Adding elements to Map
    map.put(2, "John");
    map.put(4, "Samyuktha");
    map.put(3, "jasmin");
    System.out.println("Iterating Hashmap...");

    // way 1 (java 8 Method)
    map.forEach((key, value) -> {
        System.out.println(key + " : " + value);
    });

    // way 2 (java 7 Method)
    for (Map.Entry me : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(me.getKey() + " : " + me.getValue());
    }

    // way 3 (java 6 Method)
    for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(map.get(key));
    }

    // way 4 (Legacy way to iterate HashMap)
    Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator(); // map.keySet().iterator()
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
        System.out.println(me.getKey() + " : " + me.getValue());
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 24):

> If I have an object implementing the Map interface in Java and I wish to iterate over every pair contained within it, what is the most efficient way of going through the map?

If efficiency of looping the keys is a priority for your app, then choose a `Map` implementation that maintains the keys in your desired order.

> Will the ordering of elements depend on the specific map implementation that I have for the interface?

Yes, absolutely.

- Some `Map` implementations promise a certain iteration order, others do not.
- Different implementations of `Map` maintain different ordering of the key-value pairs.

See this table I created summarizing the various `Map` implementations bundled with Java 11. Specifically, notice the *iteration order* column. Click/tap to zoom.

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features]

You can see there are **four `Map` implementations maintaining an order**:

- `TreeMap`
- `ConcurrentSkipListMap`
- `LinkedHashMap`
- `EnumMap`

### `NavigableMap` interface

Two of those implement the [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) interface: `TreeMap` & `ConcurrentSkipListMap`.

The older [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html) interface is effectively supplanted by the newer [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) interface. But you may find 3rd-party implementations implementing the older interface only.

### Natural order

If you want a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) that keeps its pairs arranged by the “natural order” of the key, use [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) or [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html). The term “natural order” means the class of the keys implements [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html). The value returned by the [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) method is used for comparison in sorting.

### Custom order

If you want to specify a custom sorting routine for your keys to be used in maintaining a sorted order, pass a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) implementation appropriate to the class of your keys. Use either [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) or [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html), passing your `Comparator`.

### Original insertion order

If you want the pairs of your map to be kept in their original order in which you inserted them into the map, use [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

### Enum-definition order

If you are using an enum such as [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) or [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) as your keys, use the [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html) class. Not only is this class *highly* optimized to use very little memory and run very fast, it maintains your pairs in the order defined by the enum. For `DayOfWeek`, for example, the key of `DayOfWeek.MONDAY` will be first found when iterated, and the key of `DayOfWeek.SUNDAY` will be last.

### Other considerations

In choosing a `Map` implementation, also consider:

- NULLs. Some implementations forbid/accept a NULL as key and/or value.
- Concurrency. If you are manipulating the map across threads, you must use an implementation that supports concurrency. Or wrap the map with [`Collections::synchronizedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)) (less preferable).

Both of these considerations are covered in the graphic table above.

Comment: Late comment on an answer that's also late to the party (but very informative). +1 from me for mentioning `EnumMap`, since it's the first time I've heard of it. There's probably many cases where this might come in handy.

Answer (score 22):

If you have a generic untyped Map you can use:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
for (Map.Entry entry : ((Set<Map.Entry>) map.entrySet())) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 21):

```
public class abcd {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<Integer, String> testMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        testMap.put(10, "a");
        testMap.put(20, "b");
        testMap.put(30, "c");
        testMap.put(40, "d");

        for (Integer key : testMap.keySet()) {
            String value = testMap.get(key);
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
public class abcd {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<Integer, String> testMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        testMap.put(10, "a");
        testMap.put(20, "b");
        testMap.put(30, "c");
        testMap.put(40, "d");

        for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : testMap.entrySet()) {
            Integer key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry element = (Map.Entry) it.next();
    LOGGER.debug("Key: " + element.getKey());
    LOGGER.debug("value: " + element.getValue());    
}
```

Answer (score 15):

An effective iterative solution over a Map is a `for` loop from Java 5 through Java 7. Here it is:

```
for (String key : phnMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key: " + key + " Value: " + phnMap.get(key));
}
```

From Java 8, you can use a lambda expression to iterate over a Map. It is an enhanced `forEach`

```
phnMap.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("Key: " + k + " Value: " + v));
```

If you want to write a conditional for lambda you can write it like this:

```
phnMap.forEach((k,v) -> {
    System.out.println("Key: " + k + " Value: " + v);
    if ("abc".equals(k)) {
        System.out.println("Hello abc");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 14):

You can do it using generics:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> entries = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (entries.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = entries.next();
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
//Functional Operations
Map<String, String> mapString = new HashMap<>();
mapString.entrySet().stream().map((entry) -> {
    String mapKey = entry.getKey();
    return entry;
}).forEach((entry) -> {
    String mapValue = entry.getValue();
});

//Intrator
Map<String, String> mapString = new HashMap<>();
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = mapString.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Map.Entry<String, String> entry = it.next();
    String mapKey = entry.getKey();
    String mapValue = entry.getValue();
}

//Simple for loop
Map<String, String> mapString = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mapString.entrySet()) {
    String mapKey = entry.getKey();
    String mapValue = entry.getValue();

}
```

Answer (score 14):

Use Java 8:

```
map.entrySet().forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 13):

Yes, as many people agreed this is the best way to iterate over a `Map`.

But there are chances to throw `NullPointerException` if the map is `null`. Don't forget to put `null` .check in.

```
                                                 |
                                                 |
                                         - - - -
                                       |
                                       |
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Object value = entry.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Iterating a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is very easy.

```
for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
   Object value = map.get(key);
   // Do your stuff
}
```

For instance, you have a `Map<String, int> data;`

```
for (Object key : data.keySet()) {
  int value = data.get(key);
}
```

Comment: Well, this is unnecessarily slow because first get the keys and then the entries. Alternative: Get the entrySets and then for each entryset the key and the value

Answer (score 11):

There are a lot of ways to do this. Below is a few simple steps:

Suppose you have one Map like:

```
Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Then you can do something like the below to iterate over map elements.

```
// ********** Using an iterator ****************
Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> me = m.entrySet().iterator();
while(me.hasNext()){
    Entry<String, Integer> pair = me.next();
    System.out.println(pair.getKey() + ":" + pair.getValue());
}

// *********** Using foreach ************************
for(Entry<String, Integer> me : m.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(me.getKey() + " : " + me.getValue());
}

// *********** Using keySet *****************************
for(String s : m.keySet()){
    System.out.println(s + " : " + m.get(s));
}

// *********** Using keySet and iterator *****************
Iterator<String> me = m.keySet().iterator();
while(me.hasNext()){
    String key = me.next();
    System.out.println(key + " : " + m.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("ram", "ayodhya");
        map.put("krishan", "mathura");
        map.put("shiv", "kailash");

        System.out.println("********* Keys *********");
        Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            System.out.println(key);
        }

        System.out.println("********* Values *********");
        Collection<String> values = map.values();
        for (String value : values) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }

        System.out.println("***** Keys and Values (Using for each loop) *****");
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + "\t Value: "
                    + entry.getValue());
        }

        System.out.println("***** Keys and Values (Using while loop) *****");
        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> entries = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, String> entry = (Map.Entry<String, String>) entries
                    .next();
            System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + "\t Value: "
                    + entry.getValue());
        }

        System.out
                .println("** Keys and Values (Using java 8 using lambdas )***");
        map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out
                .println("Key: " + k + "\t value: " + v));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

## `Map.forEach`

What about simply using [`Map::forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#forEach(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) where both the key and the value are passed to your [`BiConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html)?

```
map.forEach((k,v) -> {
    System.out.println(k + "->" + v);
});
```

Comment: This was covered in the [Answer by Lova Chittumuri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57321787/642706). Also covered as item # 3 in the highly-upvoted [Answer by Viacheslav Vedenin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35558955/642706).

Comment: But only available in API label 24

Answer (score 7):

Here is a generic type-safe method which can be called to dump any given `Map`.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapUtils {
    static interface ItemCallback<K, V> {
        void handler(K key, V value, Map<K, V> map);
    }

    public static <K, V> void forEach(Map<K, V> map, ItemCallback<K, V> callback) {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<K, V> entry = it.next();

            callback.handler(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), map);
        }
    }

    public static <K, V> void printMap(Map<K, V> map) {
        forEach(map, new ItemCallback<K, V>() {
            @Override
            public void handler(K key, V value, Map<K, V> map) {
                System.out.println(key + " = " + value);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Example

Here is an example of its use. Notice that the type of the `Map` is inferred by the method.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MapPrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Map<?, ?>> maps = new ArrayList<Map<?, ?>>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            {
                add(new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    {
                        put("One", 0);
                        put("Two", 1);
                        put("Three", 3);
                    }
                });

                add(new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    {
                        put("Object", new Object());
                        put("Integer", new Integer(0));
                        put("Double", new Double(0.0));
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        for (Map<?, ?> map : maps) {
            MapUtils.printMap(map);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

```
One = 0
Two = 1
Three = 3

Object = java.lang.Object@15db9742
Integer = 0
Double = 0.0
```

Answer (score 7):

Since Java 10, you can use local variable inference (a.k.a. "var") to make a lot of the already available answers less bloated. For example:

```java
for (var entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to iterate a map. Please refer to the following code.

When you iterate a map using the `Iterator` Interface you must go with `Entry<K,V>` or `entrySet()`.

It looks like this:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class IteratMapDemo {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Map<String, String> mapOne = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mapOne.put("1", "January");
        mapOne.put("2", "February");
        mapOne.put("3", "March");
        mapOne.put("4", "April");
        mapOne.put("5", "May");
        mapOne.put("6", "June");
        mapOne.put("7", "July");
        mapOne.put("8", "August");
        mapOne.put("9", "September");
        mapOne.put("10", "Octomber");
        mapOne.put("11", "November");
        mapOne.put("12", "December");

        Iterator it = mapOne.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            // System.out.println("Get Key through While loop = " + me.getKey());
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry:mapOne.entrySet()) {
            // System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
        }

        for (Object key : mapOne.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + key.toString() + " Value: " +
                               mapOne.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: keySet() is slow

Answer (score 6):

If your reason for iterating trough the `Map`, is to do an operation on the value and write to a resulting `Map`. I recommend using the `transform`-methods in the [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) `Maps` class.

```
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
```

After you have added the `Maps` to your imports, you can use `Maps.transformValues` and `Maps.transformEntries` on your maps, like this:

```
public void transformMap() {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("a", 2);
    map.put("b", 4);

    Map<String, Integer> result = Maps.transformValues(map, num -> num * 2);
    result.forEach((key, val) -> print(key, Integer.toString(val)));
    // key=a,value=4
    // key=b,value=8

    Map<String, String> result2 = Maps.transformEntries(map, (key, value) -> value + "[" + key + "]");
    result2.forEach(this::print);
    // key=a,value=2[a]
    // key=b,value=4[b]
}

private void print(String key, String val) {
    System.out.println("key=" + key + ",value=" + val);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I like to concat a counter, then save the final value of the counter;

```
int counter = 0;
HashMap<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    m.put("firstname" + i, items.get(i).getFirstName());
    counter = i;
}

m.put("recordCount", String.valueOf(counter));
```

Then when you want to retrieve:

```
int recordCount = Integer.parseInf(m.get("recordCount"));
for (int i = 0; i < recordCount; i++)
{
    System.out.println("First Name :" + m.get("firstname" + i));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Using  Java 7

```
Map<String,String> sampleMap = new HashMap<>();
for (sampleMap.Entry<String,String> entry : sampleMap.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();

    /* your Code as per the Business Justification  */

}
```

> Using Java 8

```
Map<String,String> sampleMap = new HashMap<>();

sampleMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key is :  " + k + " Value is :  " + v));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can search for the key and with the help of the key you can find the associated value of the map as the map has **unique key**, see what happens when the key is duplicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20537942/9898251) or [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29).

Demo map :

```java
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap();
map.put("name", "Name");
map.put("age", "23");
map.put("address", "NP");
map.put("faculty", "BE");
map.put("major", "CS");
map.put("head", "MDK");
```

To get the key only, you can use `map.keySet();` like this :

```java
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

To get value only, you can use `map.values();` like this:

```java
for (String value : map.values()) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

To get both the key and its value, you still can use `map.keySet();` and get its corresponding value, like this:

```java
// this prints the key + value pair
for (String k : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(k + " " + map.get(k) + " ");
}
```

`map.get(key)` gives the value pointed by that key.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't quite answer the OP's question, but might be useful to others who find this page:

If you only need the values and not the keys, you can do this:

```
Map<Ktype, Vtype> myMap = [...];
for (Vtype v: myMap.values()) {
  System.out.println("value: " + v);
}
```

`Ktype`, `Vtype` are pseudocode.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to iterate through the map in the order that the elements were added, use `LinkedHashMap` as opposed to just `Map`.

This approach has worked for me in the past:

```java
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> test = new LinkedHashMap();

test.put("foo", 69);
test.put("bar", 1337);

for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(test.get(test.keySet().toArray()[i]));
}
```

Output:

```
69
1337
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Map<String, String> map = 
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    MapKey = entry.getKey() 
    MapValue = entry.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I copied the data of a map to another with this code:

```java
HashMap product = (HashMap) shopping_truck.get(i);
HashMap tmp = new HashMap();
for (Iterator it = product.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Map.Entry thisEntry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
    tmp.put(thisEntry.getKey(), thisEntry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest way of doing it I believe...

```
/* For example, this could be a map object */
Map<String, Integer> MAP = new Map<>();

// Do something like put keys/value pairs into the map, etc...
MAP.put("Denver", 35);
MAP.put("Patriots", 14);

/* Then, simply use a for each loop like this to iterate */
for (Object o : MAP.entrySet()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) o;
    // Do whatever with the pair here (i.e. pair.getKey(), or pair.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Past answers are ok but I feel an explanation of each solution and time complexity will go long one to anyone searching for this.

1. Using entrySet() and for-each loop:

   ```
    Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put("Alice", 25);
    myMap.put("Bob", 30);
    myMap.put("Charlie", 20);

    // Using entrySet()
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Integer value = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
    }
   ```

**Explanation:**

- myMap.entrySet() returns a set of key-value pairs (Map.Entry objects).
- The for-each loop iterates directly over these entries.
  **Time Complexity:**
- Best/Average/Worst Case: O(n), where 'n' is the number of entries in the map. This is because it iterates through each entry once.

**Overall Complexity:**

- Linear, making it very efficient.

2. Using entrySet(), Iterator, and while loop:

```java
    Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        myMap.put("Alice", 25);
        myMap.put("Bob", 30);
        myMap.put("Charlie", 20);
    // Using Iterator
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> iterator = myMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = iterator.next();
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Integer value = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
    }
```

**Explanation:**

- myMap.entrySet().iterator() gets an iterator for the entry set.
- iterator.hasNext() checks if there's another element.
- iterator.next() gets the next entry and moves the iterator forward.

**Time Complexity:**

- Best/Average/Worst Case: O(n), same as the for-each loop.
- Overall Complexity: Linear. Compared to the earlier code written, this solution gives you the flexibility of using an iterator if you need to remove elements during the iteration safely.

3. Using Java 8 Lambda function

```java
 Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
 myMap.put("Alice", 25);
 myMap.put("Bob", 30);
 myMap.put("Charlie", 20);
// Using forEach()
myMap.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + value));
```

**Explanation**

- myMap.forEach() takes a lambda expression (a concise function) that's applied to each entry. Here, we simply print the key-value pair.
  **Time Complexity:**
- Best/Average/Worst Case: O(n), the same as the other methods.
- Overall Complexity: Linear. Provides a more concise syntax if you only need to process elements and don't require an iterator.

**Conclusion**
All of these methods are effectively equally efficient. In most cases, the choice comes down to readability and whether you need the flexibility of an iterator:

- For-each loop (entrySet): Clean syntax for simple iteration.
- Iterator: Useful if you might need to remove entries while iterating.
- forEach(): follows functional-style approach which is concise